# how to do a gallery using display grid

Tags: php, html, css, css-grid

I would like to know if anyone can help me make a gallery using display grid.

For example:

- If I have 1 image, it should fill all available space.

> Each line should have a maximum of 3 images.

- If I have 3 images: the first one fills 100% and the other two go to the bottom line and get 50% each.
- if you have 4 pictures: the first one fills 100% and the other 3 go to the bottom line and get + - 33% each.
- If I have 5 img: the first one occupies 100% and the other 3 go to the bottom line and get + - 33% each and fifth img goes to the next line filling 100% and so on.

[example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tch0g.png)

[example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGK3V.png)

[example 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtEBY.png)

I'm using php - pug to do it

```
mixin galery-images(array)
 .galery-images
    each el, index in array  
      if index == 0 
        .col.first-img
          img(src=el.img, alt=el.title)
```

css

```
& img {
    display: block;
  }

  & :nth-child(1n) {
    width: 360px;
    height: 190px;

    margin: 20px 16px 5px 16px;

    grid-row: 1;
  }

  & :nth-child(2n) {
    grid-row: 1;

    margin: 5px auto;
  }

  & :nth-child(3n) {
    grid-row: 1;

    margin: 5px auto;
  }

  & :nth-child(4n) {
    grid-row: 1;

    margin: 5px auto;
  }
```

Thanks so much for your help guys.

Comment: for the parent element set ```width: 100%``` and for each image set ```flex: 33%``` and then do ```flex-wrap: wrap; flex-direction: row;```

Comment: but if i have 3 img, first 100% it's ok, but the others must be 50%. And i don't know how much imgs will exists, must be dynamic

Comment: Ok then, I do not really understand your question. Please elaborate in a way that makes sense

Comment: you could try ```flex: 500px``` or something

Comment: I suggest you figure out what you want... and then figure out the best tools - instead of choosing a tool - and then trying to make it do something... you know? Like - how to I screw in a screw with a hammer... is kinda a weird question.

Comment: You'd probably make a gallery... and then put it in a box (inside your grid layout)